# how to full outer join tables and sum up in PIG

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, outer-join

I Have 2 data sets as below on HDFS that are Tab separated:

```
A
--------
DATE          PAGE VIEWS      CLICKS
2014/01/21    200             50
2014/01/22    300             70
2014/01/23    150             100

B
--------
DATE          PAGE VIEWS      CLICKS
2014/01/23    50              25
2014/01/24    250             110
```

I would like to merge these 2 data sets to produce the following result:

```
C
--------
DATE          PAGE VIEWS      CLICKS
2014/01/21    200             50
2014/01/22    300             70
2014/01/23    200             125
2014/01/24    250             110
```

As you can see, the final data set C, has got the aggregate data for 2014/01/23 from both A & B, and included records from A not in B and vice versa. I know this can be acheived in PIG using a FULL OUTER JOIN but am not sure of a clean solution. In SQL, I could acheive the same as follows:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(A.DATE, B.DATE) AS DATE, 
SUM(COALESCE(A.PAGE_VIEWS, 0)+COALESCE(B.PAGE_VIEWS, 0)) AS PAGE_VIEWS,
SUM(COALESCE(A.CLICKS, 0)+COALESCE(B.CLICKS, 0)) AS CLICKS
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B 
ON A.DATE = B.DATE
GROUP BY COALESCE(A.DATE, B.DATE);
```

Would appreciate some guidance on how to implement this in PIG 0.10! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it could be:

```
 AB1 = UNION A, B;
 AB2 = GROUP AB1 BY DATE;
 C = FOREACH AB2 GENERATE group AS DATE, SUM(PAGE_VIEWS) AS PAGE_VIEWS, SUM(CLICKS) AS CLICKS;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Let me try this out, seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to use `COGROUP`.  `COGROUP` is like `GROUP`, except you apply the grouping to multiple aliases and as a result you have one bag of records for each of them, instead of just a single bag of records.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately in this case, because of the way Pig handles bag projection from empty bags, if `A` or `B` doesn't have a record for a given `DATE`, that bag of records will be empty, the projection of a column will result in a `NULL` bag, the `SUM` of that is `NULL`, and then when you add that to the other value, it turns the whole expression into a `NULL`.  So the code has to become a little uglier to account for this.

```
C =
    FOREACH (COGROUP A BY DATE, B BY DATE)
    GENERATE
        group AS DATE,
        (IsEmpty(A)?0:SUM(A.PAGE_VIEWS))+(IsEmpty(B)?0:SUM(B.PAGE_VIEWS)) AS PAGE_VIEWS,
        (IsEmpty(A)?0:SUM(A.CLICKS))+(IsEmpty(B)?0:SUM(B.CLICKS)) AS CLICKS;
```

`COGROUP` is essential, however, if you wish to apply different operations to the different bags, so keep it in mind even if you decide that a `UNION`/`GROUP` solution is cleaner in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What would perform better, a UNION approach above or using COGROUP? The source datasets are not very big.

Comment: Since your datasets are small, the main consideration is how many map-reduce jobs are launched -- I haven't tried it, but both `UNION` and `GROUP`/`COGROUP` require reduce phases, and I don't think Pig is able to combine them, so the `UNION`/`GROUP` approach would require 2 MR jobs, while the `COGROUP` approach would just require 1. But you can try them out to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the COGROUP approach, however it seems to be doing an INNER JOIN. The resulting output only has data for 2014/01/23. I tried the syntax 'FOREACH (COGROUP A BY DATE OUTER, B BY DATE OUTER)' but that still returns only 2014/01/23 data. What should the correct statement be to ensure a full outer join, using COGROUP?

Comment: See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#GROUP for the details on how `COGROUP` works.  `OUTER` is meaningless in this context. It's not doing any kind of filtering as with an inner `JOIN`, but it is getting confused by trying to take a `SUM` when the bag is empty. I've updated the answer to reflect that. Also, I tried both methods and it turns out that Pig can optimize both of them to be done in 1 MR job.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. Will keep this in mind for the future.